# GPG Error Updating Ubuntu/Debian Packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am attempting to update my Ubuntu/Debian system and I am getting an error:

```
GPG error: http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E585066A30C18A2B
```

What does it mean, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following approach, is from [there](http://www.vntweb.co.uk/no_pubkey-e585066a30c18a2b/)

> The error `NO_PUBKEY E585066A30C18A2B` is the key for the Opera web
>   browser. To correct the error, run the following code.
>
> `wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo wget -O - http://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add
--2016-09-24 09:42:48--  http://deb.opera.com/archive.key
Resolving deb.opera.com (deb.opera.com)... 185.26.183.130
Connecting to deb.opera.com (deb.opera.com)|185.26.183.130|:80...     connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ERROR: This command can only be     used by root.
200 OK
Length: 3152 (3,1K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

-                     0%[                    ]       0  --.-KB/s    in 0s      


Cannot write to ‘-’ (Broken pipe).
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of `apt` also support

```
apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://deb.opera.com/archive.key
```

instead of

```
wget -qO - https://deb.opera.com/archive.key | apt-key add -
```

Additionally, you should always use **https** when loading the key.